# CanCan skip_authorization_check not working with rails json api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm creating an app and I want to expose the create method in this controller as an api endpoint.

This does not work and shows the error `You are not authorized to access this page`. Why does the `skip_authorization_check` not get honored?

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

    load_and_authorize_resource
    skip_authorization_check :only => [:invalid_site, :create]


...

    # POST /accounts
    # POST /accounts.json
    def create

    puts "in create"
        #authorize! :create, current_user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
        @account = Account.new(account_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @account.save
                format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @account }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

...

    private

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def account_params
      puts params.inspect
            params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, :billing_email)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I also had to add `skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => :create`. If someone could more clearly explain all these different skip methods that'd be helpful to the rest of the googlers: http://rubydoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/master/frames/CanCan/ControllerAdditions/ClassMethods

Answer (score 0):

Minor aside - consider switching to CanCanCan as CanCan no longer maintained.

apologies - meant to add this as a comment not an answer

Comment: I did switch to CanCanCan and still had the same issue.